# Oracle session and process reaching max utilization issue with Oracle 18c+Tomcat9

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

Currently we migrated to Oracle 18c+ Tomcat 9 after which we are experiencing high utilization issue with both processes and sessions.

```
 INST_ID RESOURCE_NAME        CURRENT_UTILIZATION MAX_UTILIZATION LIMIT_VALUE
 -------- -------------------- ------------------- --------------- ------------
     1    processes                      925            1000       1000
     1    sessions                       945            1020       1522
```

On further querying most of the utilization are observed from DB,

```
SELECT machine, count(*) FROM v$session GROUP BY machine ORDER BY count(*) DESC;

             MACHINE     COUNT(*)
             --------     ----------
             1825(DB)       591
             0058(APP)      332
```

How can I address this issue and find an permanent solution? As a temporary workaround I'm clearing all inactive sessions from the database using `kill session`.

My `server.xml`:

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
   connectionTimeout="20000"
   acceptCount="500"
   maxSavePostSize="0"
   disableUploadTimeout="true"
   enableLookups="false"
   maxThreads="450"
   removeAbandonedTimeout="60" removeAbandoned="true"
    logAbandoned="true"
    SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"   />
```

---

```
SELECT (
     (SELECT SUM(value) FROM V$SGA) -
      (SELECT CURRENT_SIZE FROM V$SGA_DYNAMIC_FREE_MEMORY)
      ) "SGA_TARGET"
      FROM DUAL;--8589930592
```

---

```
 Select POOL, Round(bytes/1024/1024,0) Free_Memory_In_MB 
 From V$sgastat Where Name Like '%free memory%';
         shared pool    378
         large pool     16
         streams pool   32


      INACTIVE SESSION
     ======================                                                         
      USERNAME       PROGRAM                              COUNT                                                              
     -----------------------------------------------------------------                                   
     Schema1              SQL Developer                            1
     Schema2              JDBC Thin Client                        43
     Schema1             JDBC Thin Client                          20
     SYS    rman@czcholspc000439.prg-dc.dhl.com (TNS V1-V3)        34
     DBSNMP             JDBC Thin Client                          28
     DBSNMP                 OMS                                    1
```

Comment: Who owned the inactive sessions?

Comment: You might post the output of this query to show what waits the active sessions are waiting on. select event,count(*) cnt from v$session group by event order by cnt desc; It could be that sessions are hanging on something and new sessions are getting spawned.

Comment: The question asked by @MichaelKutz about who owned the inactive sessions is important: many necessary background sessions exist - and many/most will appear to be "inactive" at any given time - that should NOT be killed. Sessions only show as "active" if they are actually executing SQL in the exact instant you happen to run your query. "inactive" doesn't mean "unused".

Comment: That said, what is the problem that you are trying to solve? Can you increase the process limit? Is there actually a resource (memory or cpu) issue on your server?

Comment: What are you migrating from?  What you are describing might indicate that your application code is leaking connections.  It might indicate that you've configured your connection pools incorrectly.  It might indicate that you want to use shared server connections in Oracle rather than dedicated server.  Not enough information in the question to know but if we at least know what configuration was previously working we might be able to narrow down the most likely source of the issue

Comment: @MichaelKutz: Sorry for the delay. The inactive sessions list i have updated above.

Comment: @pmdba: Thanks for the suggestion. I am looking for an permanent solution. Increasing the process limit still doesnt solve the problem as the process and session count still gonna exceed:(

Comment: @JustinCave: We migrated recently from 18C to 19C DB.Earlier it was 12C. Actually we didn't face this issue in 12C DB. But both in 18C and 19C we are facing this issue. The same application code worked well with 12C . Also could you please let me know what is the benefit of Shared Server Connection.

Comment: @BobbyDurrett: Thanks for replying. Have included the event name in the original question. Please help me how to take it forward. From application side all the leaks are addressed.But my worry is the same code worked well in 12c but why the issue happens in 18 n 19C.

Comment: I see many sessions of RMAM connected. Did you upgrade that? Also, being unfamiliar with SMNP, I'd be worried about those SMNP connections. For the others, can they be explained by the Connection Pool settings of Tomcat?

Comment: DBSNMP is Oracle's internal monitoring via tools like Enterprise Manager. The number of RMAN connections suggest running backup jobs. My point with asking about system resources is that the default limits for things like processes and sessions are _arbitrary_. If you're not experiencing a resource shortage of memory or cpu on your server then there's no reason you can't increase those limits.

Comment: Sessions get spawned for all kinds of things - many of them for background processes that can vary between versions. if you recently upgraded, that could very well explain the increase. If you didn't adjust those process limits accordingly, you may very well need to do that now. If increasing the limits still results in the same problem and you don't have room to increase more, then you probably still have a session leak somewhere in your application.

Comment: Why the heck do you have so many RMAN and DBSNMP sessions? That looks suspicious to me. RMAN would be backup and DBSNMP OEM monitoring. Maybe when you upgraded something is not working right with these two.